# How would I attach a randomly generated string to react router useParams()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, multiplayer

**My question explanation:**

Basically I am trying to create a multiplayer web game. I am running into a logical issue when trying to understand how to get a new page to open upon "Start new Game".

I would like to randomly generate a string through a function then use that result as the :id in my url.
I can successfully create the randomly generated string, but still confused on how to use it in my useParams() for react-router v5.

---

If possible I would also like to connect a socket to each generated url that way it splits concerns easily and everything stays in place.

---

So it would be in logic of pages

1. Landing Page with Start new Game button
2. Click New game button and new tab opens with Game content that pertains to that specific game.

---

If you have any other insight to a different way to handle this, it would be greatly appreciated!

---

**my code**

*App.jsx*

```js
import React from 'react';
import Landing from './Landing/Landing.jsx';
import Game from './Game/Game.jsx';
import { HashRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Styles/styles.scss';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
                <Route exact path="/game/:id" component={Game} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default App
```

*Landing.jsx*

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';


const Landing = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const [randomRoom, setRandomRoom] = useState('');

        /*
            This functions needs to create :id for react-router and also create room id for socket.io
        */

    const getRandomString = (length) => {
            let randomChars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
            let result = '';
            for ( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
                result += randomChars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * randomChars.length));
            }
        setRandomRoom(result)
        }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => { 
                getRandomString(20);
                }}>
                Start New Game
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Landing
```

*Game.jsx*

```js
import React from 'react'

const Game = () => {
/*
  This will hold the content for game page including Map, scoreboard, usernames, list of items, etc
*/
    return (
        <div>
            HELLO FROM GAME
        </div>
    )
}

export default Game
```

[Visuals of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkCnB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since the url `/game/:id` renders the `Game` component, that's where you need to use `useParams` to get the value of that URL parameter.

So your `Game` code will look like this:

```
const Game = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();

    return (
        <div>
            HELLO FROM GAME
        </div>
    )
}
```

And then you can use that ID for whatever purpose you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using `react-router-dom`'s `Link` component, with the `to` property set to the desired URL (including the `:id` section).

Then, you can make the network requests from the new page, extracting the `id:` section of the URL using `useParams`:

```js
/// first-page.jsx
export const FirstPage = () => {

  const getRandomString = useCallback(() => {
    // generate your string...
    return 'your_random_string';
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>Some other components ...</div>
      <Link
        to={`/second/page/:${getRandomString()}`}
      >
        Start Game!
      </Link>
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
/// second-page.jsx
export const Secondpage = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>The page's ID is: {id}</div>
  );
};
```

```
/// index.jsx
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/first/page">
        <FirstPage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/second/page/:id">
        <SecondPage />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

If you look at the route in the last snippet, you'll see that the last fragment of the URL is identified by react-router as `:id`. This matches the pattern used in the first-page and can then be read by `useParams` in second-page.

Comment: ok, so I implemented this. It seems to work except for one issue: if i click "start game," the url that is created looks like this "http://localhost:3000/#/game/:"

Maybe I have been mistaken, but shouldnt it show the string?

Comment: It should look like `localhost:3000/#/game/ID`. Did you take a look at the `react-router-dom` docs: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object

Comment: I did look at the docs. Was trying to base my code off the example provided. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Hey there @LarrySchwall. I just double checked my answer and there was a typo: the Link's to param should be `/second/page/${getRandomString()}`, not `/second/page:${getRandomString()}`. Notice the `:` becomes a `/`.

Comment: Actually i got it working! I forgot to add the length parameter in the useCallback! Thanks again for your help! 

Now to try to configure websocket rooms to match the id create on the page. You wouldnt happen to know how to do that? haha

Comment: Sorry, I don't, but if you have more questions, you can always post them here. (Also, if this answer helped, you can mark this question as answered.)